Bird.com creating workspace - An unexpected error has occurred
I have the following problem: I want to create a workspace on the bird.com service using their api, but I get a message when I create it:
{
  code: 'InternalServerError',
  message: 'An unexpected error has occurred'
}

I have a valid api key that allows me to perform manipulations in this domain. Everything happens in this code:
const createWorkspace = async (organizationId, name, region) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.post(
      `${BIRD_BASE_URL}/organizations/${organizationId}/workspaces`,
      {
        name,
        description: name,
        dataPolicy: {
          group: region.group,
          regions: [
            {
              region: region.region,
              priority: 0,
            },
          ],
        },
      },
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${BIRD_API_KEY}`,
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
      }
    );

    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error creating workspace:', error.response.data);
    return null;
  }
};

I created an apiKey, got the regions, and am using the following test router:
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  const status = await createWorkspace(
    BIRD_ORGANIZATION_ID,
    'testEU',
    birdRegion.eu
  );
  res.json(status);
});

birdRegion:
const birdRegion = {
  eu: {
    group: 'eu',
    region: 'eu-west-1',
  },
  ap: {
    group: 'ap',
    region: 'ap-south-1',
  },
  us: {
    group: 'us',
    region: 'us-west-1',
  },
};

and have next request body:
{
  "name": "testEU",
  "description": "testEU",
  "dataPolicy": {
    "group": "eu",
    "regions": [
      {
        "region": "eu-west-1",
        "priority": 0
      }
    ]
  }
}


Bird.com docs:
const response = await fetch('/organizations/{organizationId}/workspaces', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      "Authorization": "Bearer jwt",
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      "name": "text",
      "dataPolicy": {
        "group": "eu",
        "regions": [
          {
            "region": "eu-west-1"
          }
        ]
      }
    }),
});
const data = await response.json();


This HTTP response InternalServerError from bird.com suggests there is something wrong on their end, so it's likely all you can do is contact their support team.
It's worth trying the following things before you do that (in case they are not doing their error handling well):

In the headers, change Bearer to AccessKey as per the docs. Bearer is used for JSON Web Tokens (which you don't have), where as AccessKey is being used for the API key in this case.

Remove "priority": 0 from the region json body, in case there is an error in the payload.



Thank you for your response! I think I really need to seek support.
When I use accessToken, nothing changes, it seems to work the same as Bearer, other requests go through fine with both accessToken and Bearer. If I remove the “priority” I get an error that this field is required.
